# Track employee browsing on mobile broadband

Tags: internet, user-tracking

We've a few employees to whom we need to give mobile broadband dongles (along with laptops) on a regular basis.

I'm tasked with finding ways to track employee browsing outside of our company's domain network (on mobile broadband).

*specific question* - We've got Symantic endpoint protection antivirus installed on each corporate laptop given along with the dongle. What settings we need to do so that we can get browsing records? If it's getting recorded by default, from where we can get the browsing data?

Is there a possibility?

Comment: It actually depends on whether the device can be customized but that's fairly unlikely.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, since the dongle connects to outside network directly. (This is assuming that there is no configuration that you can do on the dongle to set up IP/domain filtering, similar to a router).

Comment: @JuliePelletier (specific question) We've got Symantic endpoint protection antivirus installed on each corporate laptop given along with the dongle. What settings we need to do so that we can get browsing records? If it's getting recorded by default, from where we can get the browsing data?

Comment: If it's a corporate laptop, then you have admin rights and probably legal power to install any kind of logging system.  It's a completely different story.

Comment: We cannot help you configure proprietary monitoring/logging tools within an enterprise. [Symant***e***c](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.DOC8645.html) has 800+ pages of documentation to help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be difficult on the device itself. I'd contact the mobile provider for any options with the device. They may have some logging capabilities they can share with the customer.

If you're interested in tracking the corporate devices connected to the mobile broadband there are a couple of options:

- End Point Protection & Monitoring Solutions (e.g., Carbon Black, Tanium, Avast, Trend, *the list goes on*)
- Mobile Device Management Software (MDMs) (e.g., MobileIron, Airwatch, Sophos, *the list goes on*)
- Content Filtering Proxies (e.g., Websense Remote Filter, I'm sure there are others)

*Note: these options are not exclusive to the broadband dongle, they will allow monitoring / control of the device when connected to **any** offsite network*.

Comment: (specific question) We've got Symantic endpoint protection antivirus installed on each corporate laptop given along with the dongle. What settings we need to do so that we can get browsing records? If it's getting recorded by default, from where we can get the browsing data?

Comment: @student it depends on whether the Symantec EPM is configured to log to a master logging server, if so, have you seen this: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/where-can-i-find-sepm-logs

Comment: Logging locally? Have you seen this: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/where-c-drive-we-can-find-sep-client-log

Comment: I'm not able to find any of these locations on the laptops. Do I need to do some settings for that?